# Can you refer to more than one base template in django?

Tags: django, templates, extend

I have a Django app with one base template called "base.html". This template provides for the look and feel of all pages in the website. On many - though not all - of these pages, I want to pull data from my database and display it in a consistent format. I'd like to create the template for that format in a different base called, say, "base2.html". This would mean that on pages where I present data, I will need to extend both "base.html" and "base2.html". How do I extend from two html pages on the same page?

Comment: I think you'd want to use the `{% include 'template.html' %}` tag.

Answer (score 2):

I would try this,

in views where you want a different base I would send a key in request data like so

In views.py

```
def some_view_one(request):
    different_base =  "base1.html"
    return render(request, 'customer/parent_template.html', {'different_base': different_base})

def some_view_two(request):
    different_base =  "base2.html"
    return render(request, 'customer/parent_template.html', {'different_base': different_base})
```

In parent_template.html in the very first line.

```
{% extend different_base %}
```

Note here that view_one would extend base1.html and view_two would extend base2.html

Haven't tried the same.

Please let me know.

Comment: This makes sense. In short, you are creating two bases. One base for when you are not pulling data from the database and one base when you are. And then you extend from one or the other base as needed. That's a great solution. Thanks.

Comment: Please do let me know if it works. We may do this functionality using template tags too.. But that requires more understanding of the scenario.

Comment: This works when you are pulling data once.  In my case, I have articles in a database that have attributes likes title, author, date published, etc. When I publish this information on a webpage, I want the info from each article to appear in its own box and I want that box formatted in a uniform way (the CSS/HTML for the box should be the template). My problem is I can't put the box in a base template and then just extend from that template because I need to display that box over and over again when I display article information using a for loop.